# How build an index from MSSQL server to Postgres?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, indexing

I have Index from MsSQL server like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ClickedCampaigns_UserId] ON [dbo].    [CookieUserRtbMathings] 
(
 [UserId] ASC
)
    INCLUDE ( [Id])
```

As I know there is no "Include" in Postgres, So how I can convert this index to run in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is not a unique index, you can simply add that column to the index:

```
CREATE INDEX clickedcampaigns_userid 
   ON dbo.cookieuserrtbmathings(userid, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Index with index only scans as defined in Postresql > 9.2 versions

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ClickedCampaigns_UserId] ON [dbo].    [CookieUserRtbMathings] 
(
 [UserId], ID
)
```

Comment: This is invalid for Postgres. There is no key word `nonclustered` and using `[` or `]` in an identifier is illegal SQL syntax.